# ArangoDB Services from Web Interface not accessible

Tags: docker, arangodb, nosql

I've started ArangoDB from a docker container with -e ARANGO_NO_AUTH=1 and mapped the volumes ***/var/lib/arangodb3*** and ***/var/lib/arangodb3-apps*** to my local drive. Next i wanted to create a new app but when i click **Services** from the web interface i get following error:

**`GET http://127.0.0.1:8529/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/foxxes 400 (Bad Request)`**

Do i need to be authenticated to do that or is this a docker problem? There are no errors in the log.

Im using the latest version from docker hub in this case version 2.8.9

Docker command:

```
docker run -e ARANGO_NO_AUTH=1 -p 8529:8529 --name arangodb-i -v /home/me/projects/dbs/arango/db:/var/lib/arangodb3 -v /home/me/projects/dbs/arango/apps:/var/lib/arangodb3-apps arangodb/arangodb
```

ArangoDB Info:

```
INFO ArangoDB 3.0.0 [linux] 64bit, using VPack 0.1.30, ICU 54.1, V8 5.0.71.39, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
```

The error message comes in both Chrome and Firefox but not in curl.

> This error does not occur when i install arangodb in ubuntu, only when i run it with docker.

Comment: Please post the docker command you used to run ArangoDB.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the docker image needs the Authorization header set, but because of the `ARANGO_NO_AUTH` it doesn't seem to matter what it's set to:

```
docker run --rm -e ARANGO_NO_AUTH=1 -p 8529:8529 arangodb/arangodb:3.0.0
curl  -H "Authorization: foo bar" http://127.0.0.1:8529/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/foxxes
[{"mountId":"81","mount":"/_api/gharial","name":"gharial","description":"ArangoDB Graph Module","author":"ArangoDB GmbH","system":true,"development":false,"contributors":[{"name":"Michael Hackstein","email":"m.hackstein@arangodb.com"}],"license":"Apache License, Version 2.0","version":"3.0.0","path":"/usr/share/arangodb3/js/apps/system/_api/gharial/APP","config":{},"deps":{},"scripts":{}},{"mountId":"75","mount":"/_admin/aardvark","name":"aardvark","description":"ArangoDB Admin Web Interface","author":"ArangoDB GmbH","system":true,"development":false,"contributors":[{"name":"Heiko Kernbach","email":"heiko@arangodb.com"},{"name":"Michael Hackstein","email":"m.hackstein@arangodb.com"},{"name":"Lucas Dohmen","email":"lucas@arangodb.com"}],"license":"Apache License, Version 2.0","version":"3.0.0","path":"/usr/share/arangodb3/js/apps/system/_admin/aardvark/APP","config":{},"deps":{},"scripts":{}}]
```

This also works:

```
curl  --user foo:bar http://127.0.0.1:8529/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/foxxes
```

The 2.8.9 image does not have this issue.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Yes that is true. The error does not occur when you test the API via curl. But it is there for the web interface. Just click on service with the console open.

Comment: I opened an issue for this and it looks like it's fixed in 3.0.1: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1907#event-712217551